# How to auto refresh screen on orientation change, mobile design with media queries

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I have built a simple static website using media queries to resize for tablets and smart phones. I have a rotating jquery banner. I have re-sized the banner and its images with media queries. The problem is when you change orientation on smartphone/tablet the banners dimensions don't change until you do a refresh. what I would like to know is how to auto refresh the banner when orientation changes is this possible with jquery.

Comment: Just like to add that this site isn't built with jquery mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use the resize function other than refresh page

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // add the stuff here to execute the your slider again;
});
```

Check out the sample code Here http://sharetext.org/DSXR

Sample V2 - http://sharetext.org/DSYC

Otherwise you can use a some flexible Responsive slider Plug-ins 
http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/flexslider-demo/
and you can download it here 
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/downloads

Comment: where you put //add the stuff here to execute slider again do you mean the jquery that makes the slider work sorry im new to this

Comment: yes //if its really necessary to reload the page add 'location.reload();' where I add //add the stuff..

Comment: or try 

    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
         location.reload();
    });

Comment: The second one works thank you, one last question is there away to get it to only run once as the view port hits different sizes rather than on a pixel by pixel basis

Comment: i.e when the tablet media query runs refresh screen once and when the landscape phone runs refresh etc etc

Comment: i can't because the site is live and i have just set the banner to display none in the smaller view port sizes until i can resolve this i have a screen shot of it failing after window re-size

Comment: as you can see the banner goes out of sync after the image is resized with css. when the page is refreshed it works fine

Comment: also here is a link to a txt file with the full banner jquery and html [link]http://www.ajb-webdesign.co.uk/jquerybanner.txt

Comment: Add this inside document.ready()
>>> 


 $(window).bind('resize', function() {
      var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
     var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
     var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;
     $(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});
      });

Comment: it doesn't seem to work might i add that the css im using to resize the banner is .window {
 height:287px;
 width: 680px;
 
}

.image_reel img {
 height:287px;
 width: 680px;
 } this is in tablet css and is served with a media query im not sure why the banner won't refresh. thankyou for all your help so far you have been great

Comment: Still no luck with it i know now that i need to run the variables to determin the image_reel img size again like when you refresh the page but don't know how

Comment: [link]http://www.ajb-webdesign.co.uk/mainstyles.txt here are the main styles for the banner, when i use media queries for the tablet banner size i re-size it using .window {
 height:287px;
 width: 680px;
 
}


.image_reel img {
 height:287px;
 width: 680px;
 
 }

Comment: Ashley Edited the answer please check out

Comment: Ive looked at the code all that does it make the banner go off the screen. its good that it resizes the width am i missing something

Comment: yes that I Defined in in the line #108 $('.window').width($(window).width());
$('.image_reel img').width($(window).width()); and #203 $('.window').width($(window).width());
$('.image_reel img').width($(window).width()); you can replace it with your own code

Comment: Replace that two section with  $('.image_reel img').('.window').width();

Comment: and also you define your width and height .window for both orientation in css thats enough

Comment: I have repalaced the code mentioned above and defined width and height for .window now paging isn't showing. i replaced all of section 108 and all of 203 with  $('.image_reel img').('.window').width();

Comment: Thanks Ashley Keep Going _/\_